# Fields - simple question

Tags: field-theory

I know that an ordered set is one which satisfies transitivity and at least one of the following hold for all $a, b$
$$a<b, a=b, b<a$$
And for a totally ordered set 'at least one' is replaced by 'exactly one'

My question is whether an ordered field is a field with an order or with a total order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ordered field is a field with a total order. Note, however, that it's not enough for the field to be equipped with a total order; that order has to interact nicely with the field structure. E.g. if $a<b$, then we need $a+c<b+c$ for all $c$, and there is no reason for this to be true of a general total order on the field.

---

Incidentally, your terminology here seems odd. Usually (as far as I'm aware) the term "ordered set" refers to a totally ordered set. What you call an "ordered set" is a (linearly) preordered set. I wonder if you meant "at **most** one" instead of "at least one"; if so, then what you call an "order" is more commonly called a "**partial** order".

Comment: Thank you, and yes that is correct (my mistake). Incidentally, is there such a thing as a partially ordered field and if so are there any simple examples?

Comment: @KingJ [Ask and ye shall receive](https://www.amazon.com/Partially-Ordered-Algebraic-Systems-Mathematics/dp/0486483878). (Joking aside, yes, there are many examples, but I don't know enough about them to give *instructive* ones. For instance, any field can be given the *discrete* partial ordering (no element is below any other element), but that's a silly example. It might be worth asking a question here for interesting examples of partially ordered, non-totally ordered fields.)